# how to expand & collapse UIView using auto layouts

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

[image]

This is the structure inside my `UITableViewCell`, when user swipe from right to left the `view1` move and `view2` & `view3` get visible to user because `view1` was covering `view2` & `view3`.

I am trying to collapse & expand `view2` & `view3` when `view1` moves but max width of `view2` & `view3` should be 50. How can I achieve using `auto layouts`?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by assigning a width constraint to view2 & view3 in XiB or layoutSubiews (if in code) , initially set the width constraint to 0 for both views , then when user swipes set it to 50 for each one and re-layout

```
 self.view2WidthCon.constant = 50
 self.view3WidthCon.constant = 50

 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,animations:    
{
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If `view2` and `view3` will contain subviews, setting their widths to `0` will likely break their subview constraints, leading to errors.

This is the ideal use case for the `UIStackView`. Place all three views (`view1`, `view2`, and `view3`) inside a horizontal `UIStackView`. By default, set views 2 and 3 as hidden. When the user swipes left, simply show views 2 and 3 (`view2.isHidden = false` and `view3.isHidden = false`).

The advantage of this approach is that if views 2 and 3 have subviews with autolayout, they will not be broken when you hide/show the views.

To add animation, simply put this in an animation block:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3){
    view2.hidden = false // or true
    view3.hidden = false // or true
}
```